# how to get LAST_INSERT_ID via stored procedure in php

Tags: mysql

say i have a stored procedure in mysql like below

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Procedure structure for usp_insert_user_basic_info
-- ----------------------------
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `usp_insert_user_basic_info`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_insert_user_basic_info`(IN `user_first_name` varchar(200),IN `user_last_name` varchar(200),IN `user_password` text,IN `user_dob` date,IN `user_email` varchar(250))
BEGIN
    #Routine body goes here...
  INSERT INTO  `nuclear`.`user_basic_info` (
    `user_email` ,
    `user_password` ,
    `user_first_name` ,
    `user_last_name` ,
    `user_dob`,
    `user_creation_time`
    )
    VALUES (
      user_email,  user_password,  user_first_name,  user_last_name,  user_dob,NOW()
    );
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() ;

END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Table

```
    -- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for user_basic_info
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_basic_info`;
CREATE TABLE `user_basic_info` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_email` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_password` text,
  `user_first_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_last_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_creation_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

i can call this from php without any problem

```
 $resultUsp = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

but it only returns 1 for each successful insert. i guess it is saying 1 row affected!

i want it to return `LAST_INSERT_ID`

how to do it?
by the way i don't want to add any OUT parameter.
mysql_insert_id returns 0

Comment: Does your `user_basic_info` table actually have a column with the [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute?

Comment: yup . it is auto  AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Have you just tried to do a select UserId FROM user_basic_info order by userid desc limit 1? Just to see if that gives you the correct id?

Comment: @KayNelson yup it returns last id

Comment: If you have, SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @user_id;, shouldnt you also after that have SELECT @user_id?

Comment: Shouldnt you also declare the variable @user_id?

Comment: yes i forgot to delete that 'user_id'. i dont want to have any OUT parameter
@KayNelson

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get last insert id like this in SP:

```
DECLARE LID int;

SET LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html
 LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit), so he should:
DECLARE LID BIGINT UNSIGNED; instead,
in order to prevent data overflows.

Answer (score 0):

10.4.22-MariaDB

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` did not work for me, for some reason via phpMyAdmin. `last_insert_id()` did work via phphMyAdmin.

Define an `OUT` parameter when creating the procedure:

```
OUT o_ProductId BIGINT UNSIGNED
```

Then set the `OUT` parameter using all lower case.

```
SET o_ProductId = last_insert_id();
SELECT @o_ProductId;
```

UPDATE: After creating the sp via phpmyadmin using `last_insert_id();`, editing the sp allowed me to update to `LAST_INSERT_ID();`