# mysql delete after insert select

Tags: mysql, select, insert

So I have some data that is:

'38078', '4064', '48', '0', '48', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2014-09-01 00:00:52'

corresponds to columns:

(rowid, feed_rowid, feed_scans, feed_changed, feed_unchanged, feed_failures, url_dups,
pages, excluded, relevant, empty, unparsable, irrelevant, foreignlanguage, 
corrupted, duplicate, emptyparsed, date)

where the second column is an id, and for this id there will be data from multiple date, where date is the last column.

What I want to do is to sum all the data for an id from a range of date, then add the summed data into the database as one row. In the mean while I need to delete all old data that I just selected for summation BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW.

For example I have query:

INSERT INTO crawlstats.feeds_stats

(feed_rowid, feed_scans, feed_changed, feed_unchanged, feed_failures, url_dups,
pages, excluded, relevant, empty, unparsable, irrelevant, foreignlanguage, 
corrupted, duplicate, emptyparsed, date)

(SELECT feed_rowid, sum(feed_scans) as feed_scans, sum(feed_changed) as feed_changed,
sum(feed_unchanged) as feed_unchanged, sum(feed_failures) as feed_failures, sum(url_dups) as url_dups,
sum(pages) as pages, sum(excluded) as excluded, sum(relevant) as relevant, sum(empty) as empty, 
sum(unparsable) as unparsable, sum(irrelevant) as irrelevant, sum(foreignlanguage) as foreignlanguage, 
sum(corrupted) as corrupted, sum(duplicate) as duplicate, sum(emptyparsed) as emptyparsed, date('2014-09-01') as date
 FROM crawlstats.feeds_stats where feed_rowid=4784 and date>'2014-08-01' and date < '2014-09-01')

So I wanted to delete all those I just selected in the last part in this one query. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have X records for feed_RowID

You add a new record that is within the range of the limts.
So you need to exclude the row with the highest RowID and delete all the others...

```
Delete from feed_Stats 
where feed_rowid=4784 
  and date>'2014-08-01' 
  and date < '2014-09-01' 
  and RowID <> (Select max(rowID) where feed_RowID = 4784)
```

Assuming the ROWID inserted is auto number and thus the one inserted will always be the max.  Could have a timing problem if multiple users are in the system updating this feed_RowID at the same time.  Problem would likely go away if this was wrapped in a procedure and all wrapped in a transaction.

Alternatively you could have your select return the rowID it [Last_insert_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and use it to exclude.  For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650154/how-to-get-last-insert-id-via-stored-procedure-in-php)

```
DECLARE LID int;    
SET LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

So you may be able to...

```
   Delete from feed_Stats 
    where feed_rowid=4784 
      and date>'2014-08-01' 
      and date < '2014-09-01' 
      and RowID <> last_Insert_ID();
```

Comment: it seems that RowID <> (Select max(rowID) where feed_RowID = 4784) will cause the delete query not deleting anything. I tried to make delete into select and it does not return anything either. However, if I change it to  RowID <> (Select max(rowID) from crawlstats.feeds_stats where feed_RowID = 4784) then the select query will return what we want, but change it back to delete it will throw me an error: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'feeds_stats' for update in FROM clause. Any thoughts?