# I cannot get the last inserted id in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to follow this post [how to get LAST_INSERT_ID via stored procedure in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650154/how-to-get-last-insert-id-via-stored-procedure-in-php) to return the 'id' of my last inserted record via a stored procedure.

This stored procedure works well :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_tbl_domotique_components_types_insert`(IN `p_description` VARCHAR(20))
    NO SQL
INSERT INTO tbl_domotique_components_types  
    (description)
VALUES (p_description)$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, when I am trying to edit the stored procedure as follows (and save it):

```
DECLARE LID int;

INSERT INTO tbl_domotique_components_types  
    (description)
VALUES (p_description)

SET LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I get the following error message :

Error #1064 (Syntax error) next to 'DECLARE LID int;"

The table I'm inserting new records into is called 'tbl_domotique_components_types' and has two fields : 
1. id_component_type (INT(11), Primary key, Auto Increment)
2. description (VARCHAR(20), utf8_general_ci)

What am I missing? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: a ; in select command?

Comment: You haven't provided the whole code of the procedure. And please, post error messages as text, not images.

Comment: the problem is that if I click on the error message, it disappears.

Comment: You have a `CREATE PROCEDURE ...` that you haven't posted. Edit the question and add the **whole code** and the **exact error message** as **text**.

Comment: after `VALUES (p_description)` i belive there should be a `;`

Comment: Same problem here, even by adding a ; as suggested. Thanks anyway